# On the vagueness of the formulation of a problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

I have been going through a problem set in a calculus textbook (to those interested, the name of the textbook is *”Differential and Integral Calculus”* by R. Courant, Vol I), and the problem is as follows:

> Determine the maxima, minima, and points of inflection of $x^3 + 3px + q$. Discuss the nature of the roots of $x^3 + 3px + q = 0$.

The first part of the question is a rather standard problem I had no difficulties solving whatsoever. But the latter part is a total nightmare for a mathematician, I suppose. What could “discuss the nature” possibly mean? Do I have to derive Cardano’s formulæ for the roots, or am I expected to delve into the geometric reasoning behind those expressions? What is even more confusing about this whole thing is that this problem set is located at the end of the chapter on how to use derivatives to find extrema of functions and other related notions, which seemingly have nothing to do with the question. What could this all be about? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: It is a somewhat vague question, but I’d guess the author wants to know how many real roots there are and how many complex roots there are.

Comment: You don't need to actually find the roots in order to determine the *nature* of the roots. 1) You know the cubic always has at least one real root. 2) If the derivative has no real roots, then the cubic is increasing, so it can only have one real root. 3) If the derivative has real roots, then the sign of the cubic at those roots determines how many real roots the cubic itself has.

Comment: @dxiv I do not remember asking for a solution…

Comment: @Barbatulka "*Do I have to derive Cardano’s formulæ for the roots*".

Comment: @dxiv Ah, I guess I just confused myself. My apologies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also think, that the author is searching for the solutions of the equation in the Real and/or Complex domain.
Here is a similarly worded exercise with solution:

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/discuss-the-nature-of-roots-of-the-given-equationx2-2x-3-0/

Fuzzy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The author wanted to know "What could “discuss the nature” possibly mean?" It was not a mathematical question,  but he did not understand the meaning of the sentence. So I contributed a link, where an exercise was phrased in a similar way, plus, there is a written-out solution, so he could see what he had to do in this exercise.  No idea why my answer is unclear. Please, whoever feels the call  to correct my contributions, try your best to understand and don't just wipe it off.